# Uncaught (in promise) error in Chrome originating from Facebook scripts

Tags: javascript, facebook-javascript-sdk

My site is loading and one it's finished, I get the following error in the console.

```
Uncaught (in promise) ▶ j ▶ __proto__: Error
```

The error is from:

```
https://www.facebook.com/sw?s=push
```

I have facebook like share button, Facebook page like widget on my site. I also have Facebook login but my own implementation not the standard Facebook login button and it's only initiated when a user clicks a link.

The Chrome dev tool is open when I see this, obviously.

In Firefox it says `uncaught exception: undefined` but without any indication of where the error is originating from.

Any idea how to solve this?

My site running under HTTPS. ASP.NET 4.5 / C# / jQuery / Windows 2012 RC Server.

Answer (score 0):

just unchecked **Enable Browser Link** in Visual Studio by following image:

[image]